# insert an executable code in js file using another code in node 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, fs

i am trying to create a node script, which takes a xlsx file and extracts the data from it using [convert-excel-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json) and then creates a [migrate-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate-mongo) script, which will insert the data in mongo collection.

i was able to make the node script, but there is a date field in my collection. in the xlsx sheet the data is in dd/mm/yyyy format. i extracted the dates and in node script i tried to map it like

```
"startDate": new Date("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ");
```

and then inserted it into file to create the mongo script dataset using

```
fs.writeFileSync("dataToInsert.js", JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

but the migration file which was created had the date as executed result. i.e.

```
"startDate": "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ"
```

what should be done to get the data in mongo-migrate script as new Date("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ"); so that this will execute while inserting data into the mongoDb and create proper date field and not string field.

**EDIT:**
as mentioned in comments i tried

```
"startDate" : {"$date": "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ"}
```

but this works in newer node verion (tried in node 14). but this date data is neither inserted nor read, when using node v10.16.3.

Comment: try inserting into the file as `"startDate" : {"$date": "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ"}`. mongo should read it as a new date object

Comment: this works in node 14, but in nodev10.16.3 it gives error. `Could not migrate up 20220121043433-Limits.js: key $date must not start with '$'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to accomplish what you are trying to do is by the use of the `mongo-extended-json` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/ which uses the format

```
"startDate" : {"$date": "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ"}
```

It looks like the problem lies in the parsing of the data using `JSON.stringify`.
I would suggest using [EJSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson#EJSON) from the [BSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson) package to parse the data.

instead of

```
fs.writeFileSync("dataToInsert.js", JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

try

```
const { EJSON } = require('bson');
fs.writeFileSync("dataToInsert.js", EJSON.parse(newData)); //utf-8 is default option here
```

Comment: `"startDate" : {"$date": "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ"}` is not supported in node v10

Comment: did you receive the same error when using EJSON.parse?

Comment: EJSON.parse didnot work. first of all it needs the parameters as string, and if somehow i am converting it to string, i m getting error as `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`